# In laravel project , how to create a new database and some tables in that database ,then switch back to original database.

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

In normal php we can chage the connection using con at any time. how to do same in laravel?
In laravel project , how to create a new database and some tables in that database ,then switch back to original database?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure diffrent database connections in `config/database.php`
file then you can access each connection via the `connection` method on the DB facade.

For more information check this link :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Comment: i saw the documentation , for that  have to create a connection before , here i nedd to create that dynamically. any suggestion. thanks

Comment: Hi there is a good discuss about change connection dynamically in this link [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/change-database-name-of-connection-on-the-fly](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/change-database-name-of-connection-on-the-fly) and i think there is no formal way to do this and you should make some custom code for this purpose.